# jquery - toggling a div height based on current height vs. limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/M86nA/

code is this:

```
$('div.wrap').click(function(){
   var $minY = $('div.imgur-wrap').height();
   if ($minY = 280) {
      $('div.wrap').animate({height: 500});
   }else{
      $('div.wrap').animate({height: 280});
   }
});​
```

i imagine it's because it does have the new height (500) when executing the if? how can i do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: replacing "=" with "==" and removing "imgur" in selector fixes it.

Comment: `if ($minY == 280)` - there should be two equal signs here you have a single one.

Comment: That fixed it. Doh. Thanks. Solution below works too for those curious.

Comment: next time provide fiddle with same html..demo dosen't have `imgur-wrap` in it

Comment: The fiddle you linked as well as the code you showed doesn't work when only fixing `=` to `==` as you also have the class reference incorrect. Fiddle only works when also changing `div.imgur-wrap` to `div.wrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current code, fix the class reference and `=` to `==`.

Change

```
var $minY = $('div.imgur-wrap').height();
```

To

```
var $minY = $('div.wrap').height();
```

Complete code for reference:

```
$('div.wrap').click(function() {
    var $minY = $('div.wrap').height();
    if ($minY == 280) {
        $('div.wrap').animate({
            height: 500
        });
    } else {
        $('div.wrap').animate({
            height: 280
        });
    }
});​
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/ACE4J/1/)

Comment: thank you - the imgur-wrap was left over from my actual code. This worked, as bfavaretto pointed out.

Comment: @elzi: Ah, I see. I didn't realise that as it was still part of the code linked in the fiddle too. Main thing is you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [jQuery `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) like [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/M86nA/1/)

```
$('div.wrap').toggle(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: 500
    });
}, function() {
    $('div.wrap').animate({
        height: 280
    });
});​
```

jQuery will "toggle" between the functions provided in `.toggle()`, one after the other and back. Since 280px is the initial state, we fire the height 500 first, then the 280 and back again.

Comment: Thank you... that works, as did mine, I was just missing another = sign as bfavaretto pointed out. Doh.

Comment: The two methods will respond differently to rapidly clicking on the div.  Not sure whether that matters.

Comment: @Brilliand: That's true, using toggle and the above code without conditional check queues up all the clicks as it simply switches to and from. If you accidentally double click it shrinks again as they is no conditional check. While using the original code an accidental additional click  will not queue or execute. Personally I would not want a accidental double click to undo what I wanted to happen but then again it all depends on the behaviour one wants to achieve.

Comment: Actually, using the original code, repeated clicks will cause copies of `animate({height: 280})` to be queued, since that's the default behavior if the height isn't exactly 280.